# How to subtract two column from two different table using JPA Custom query

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, one-to-one

> I want to Subtract two column  of two different table, when I receive material form  worker.
> When worker will come to deposit the material,Admin enter the entry of
> the user totalDeposit ,workWithdraw table's id as workWithdraw. In
> Pending column when admin enter workWithDraw id ,there automatically
> Subtract function will occur between quantity column of WorkWithdraw
> table and totalDeposit column of Deposit Table.This process Will
> happen Through the JPA custom query
> Condition for this case It will find quantity from workwithdraw ID
> ,and then perform subtraction
> and how many material deposit  by the user, It deduct the deposit
> material amount from withdraw material and store it in the pending
> table .I use OneToOne Relational database, when I fire that api I am
> getting emptyResultDataAccessException

org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Result must not be null!
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator.invoke(MethodInvocationValidator.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.getPendingStatus(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.nilmani.workload.service.DepositService.depositMaterial(DepositService.kt:18) ~[main/:na]
at com.nilmani.workload.controller.AdminWorkController.acceptMaterial(AdminWorkController.kt:34) ~[main/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:684) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:90) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]

> DepositService.kt

```
package com.nilmani.workload.service

import com.nilmani.workload.entity.Deposit
import com.nilmani.workload.repository.DepositRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class DepositService{
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var depositRepository: DepositRepository

    fun depositMaterial(deposit: Deposit):ResponseEntity<*>{
        val receiveMaterial = Deposit(
            totalDeposit = deposit.totalDeposit,
            workWithdraw = deposit.workWithdraw,
            pending = depositRepository.getPendingStatus(deposit.workWithdraw)
        )
        //return depositRepository.save(receiveMaterial)
        return if (depositRepository.findById(receiveMaterial.id).isPresent)
            ResponseEntity.ok().body("Deposit success full")
        else
            ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().body("Deposit failed")
    }

}
```

> AdminController.kt

```
package com.nilmani.workload.controller

import com.nilmani.workload.entity.Deposit
import com.nilmani.workload.entity.WorkWithdraw
import com.nilmani.workload.model.request.ReqWorkWithdraw
import com.nilmani.workload.service.DepositService
import com.nilmani.workload.service.WorkWithdrawService
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
class AdminWorkController {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var workWithdrawService: WorkWithdrawService
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var depositService: DepositService

    @PostMapping("/newWork")
    fun saveNewWork(@ModelAttribute reqWorkWithdraw: ReqWorkWithdraw):ResponseEntity<*>{
        val saveWork= workWithdrawService.withdrawMaterial(reqWorkWithdraw)
        val respWork = ReqWorkWithdraw(
            saveWork.materialName,
            saveWork.quantity,
            saveWork.withTime,
            saveWork.worker
        )
        return ResponseEntity(respWork,HttpStatus.OK)
    }
    @PutMapping("/receive")
    fun acceptMaterial(@ModelAttribute deposit: Deposit):ResponseEntity<*>{
        return depositService.depositMaterial(deposit)
    }
}
```

> DepositRepository.kt

```
package com.nilmani.workload.repository

import com.nilmani.workload.entity.Deposit
import com.nilmani.workload.entity.WorkWithdraw
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam

interface DepositRepository:JpaRepository<Deposit,Long> {
    @Transactional
    @Query("select  Ww.quantity - d.totalDeposit from  WorkWithdraw Ww join Deposit d on Ww.id =d.id")
    fun getPendingStatus(@RequestParam("id") id: WorkWithdraw):Long
}
```

> WorkWithDraw.kt

```
package com.nilmani.workload.entity

import java.time.LocalDateTime
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
data class WorkWithdraw(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id:Long=-1,
    val materialName:String="",
    val quantity:Long=-1,
    val withTime:LocalDateTime= LocalDateTime.now(),
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Worker::class,cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    val worker: Worker
)
```

> Deposit.kt

```
package com.nilmani.workload.entity

import java.time.LocalDateTime
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
data class Deposit(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id:Long=-1,
    val totalDeposit:Long=-1,
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = WorkWithdraw::class,cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    val workWithdraw: WorkWithdraw,
    val pending: Long =-1,
    val depositTime:LocalDateTime= LocalDateTime.now()
)
```

> I want subtract function between two column from multiple table.
> deduct  totalDeposit column of Deposit table from quantity column of
> WorkWithdraw table by the help of custom query ,
> and store the result of deduct function in pending column of deposit
> table
>
> But my query not able
> to give exact result which I Want. I define query in my repository
> class

Comment: When you run that query on it's own, what does it return?

Comment: When I call  /recive api in  post man it give above type of error .I Use that query with Jpa

Comment: when separately fire this query in php myadmin it return this type of error " 1146 - Table 'work-load.workwithdraw' doesn't exist".But workWithdraw table in side my database and contain lot of data

Comment: Is the name of the table workwithdraw or workload.workwithdraw?  MySql doesn't have discrete schemas within a database AFAIK

Comment: NO in database it is work_withdraw , But In my Entity Class I define It as WorkWIthdraw

Comment: Write a Unittest to test the query and check how the generate SQL looks like

Comment: But look at the error: "work-load.workwithdraw" is the missing table.  What is that "work-load" bit?

Comment: work-load my database name